# AWK: how to reuse a result NR-times without removing END?

Tags: awk

How can I get all differences, not just one? I want to use the calculated result for each item in the third column. The dilemma is that if I remove `END` I can print `$3` but cannot have `ave`. If I leave `END` I have `ave` but not all differences.

```
awk '{sum+=$3} END {ave=sum/NR} END {print $3-ave}' coriolis_data
-0.00964   // I want to see the rest differences, how?
```

**coriolis_data**

```
.105    0.005   0.9766  0.0001  0.595   0.005
.095    0.005   0.9963  0.0001  0.595   0.005
.115    0.005   0.9687  0.0001  0.595   0.005
.105    0.005   0.9693  0.0001  0.595   0.005
.095    0.005   0.9798  0.0001  0.595   0.005
.105    0.005   0.9798  0.0001  0.595   0.005
.095    0.005   0.9711  0.0001  0.595   0.005
.110    0.005   0.9640  0.0001  0.595   0.005
.105    0.005   0.9704  0.0001  0.595   0.005
.090    0.005   0.9644  0.0001  0.595   0.005
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

then you create another array to store `$3` values. And use only 1 `END` block

```
awk '{sum+=$3;s3[NR]=$3} END {ave=sum/NR; for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print s3[i]-ave}' coriolis_data
```